# Migrating from ColdFusion MX (6, I think) to ColdFusion 7

Tags: coldfusion, adobe, upgrade, backwards-compatibility, macromedia

I'm thinking of migrating my sites from [ColdFusion MX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ColdFusion#ColdFusion_MX_6) to [ColdFusion 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ColdFusion#ColdFusion_MX_7). Are there any issues I should be aware of? I heard that ColdFusion is backwards compatible.

Answer (score 4):

Use the ColdFusion MX7's [Code Compatibility Analyzer](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Debug_18.html) on your apps.

See also ["ColdFusion MX7 Documentation"](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/7/htmldocs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm).